# Change Bokeh Datasource on input change

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

In my example i have data collected for fruits and vegetables. The data itself has the same key values which are Names and Values.

When the user changes the dropdown i would like to swap out the data in the bar graph to show the dropdown list option. How can I do this. I'm a bit lost on how to manage all of this in a custom callback.

[image]

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.glyphs import VBar
import pandas as pd

# create dataframes of data
df_fruit = pd.DataFrame({
    'values':[3, 5, 12, 21, 16], 
    'names':['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
})
source_fruit = ColumnDataSource(df_fruit)

df_vegetables = pd.DataFrame({
    'values':[3, 4, 4], 
    'names':['Peppers', 'Potatoes', 'Carrots']
})
source_vegetables = ColumnDataSource(df_vegetables)

# plot dataframes
names = df_fruit['names'].tolist()
plot = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=400, title="Data Counts", x_range=names)
plot.vbar(source=source_fruit, x="names", top="values", bottom=0, width=0.75, color="red", fill_alpha=0.7, name='fruits')

# callback for input controls
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source_fruit), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    console.log(data);

    source.change.emit();
""")

ui_view = Select(title="View", callback=callback, value="Fruit", options=["Fruit", "Vegetables"])
callback.args['ui_view'] = ui_view

# layout
layout = column(ui_view, plot)
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using categorical ranges, glyph values that do not correspond to categories in the current range are just ignored. Given this, the simples thing to do is just to "plot" both data sets up front, and then change the range in the callback:

```
# plot dataframes
names = df_fruit['names'].tolist()
plot = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=400, title="Data Counts", x_range=names)
fruit = plot.vbar(source=source_fruit, x="names", top="values", bottom=0, width=0.75, color="red", fill_alpha=0.7, name='fruits')
veg = plot.vbar(source=source_vegetables, x="names", top="values", bottom=0, width=0.75, color="red", fill_alpha=0.7, name='veg')

# callback for input controls
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(fruit=fruit, veg=veg, plot=plot), code="""
    if (ui_view.value=="Fruit") {
      plot.x_range.factors = fruit.data_source.data.names
    } else {
      plot.x_range.factors = veg.data_source.data.names
    }
""")

ui_view = Select(title="View", callback=callback, value="Fruit", options=["Fruit", "Vegetables"])
callback.args['ui_view'] = ui_view

# layout
layout = column(ui_view, plot)
show(layout)
```